# What Happens when i don't included all hierarchy of .cert files while PFX file generation

Tags: openssl, pfx

Ì am trying to a) export PFX file from the available Certificates files and private file, when I export using all the available certificate hierarchy like below - i get following error

`pkcs12 -export -out C:\Users\YSW\SCI\prp\preproduction-abc.com.pfx 
-inkey C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt  -in C:\Users\YSW\SCI\prp\pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt
-in C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt 
-in C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt 
-in C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt`

Error 
""No certificate matches private key, 
error in pkcs12""

b) When I remove certificates in hierarchy and only keep the main certificate, like below it works well for me without any error

`pkcs12 -export -out C:\Users\YSW\SCI\prp\preproduction-abc.com.pfx 
-inkey C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt  -in C:\Users\YSW\SCI\prp\pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt`

Before i upload this PFX file to the server, i want to ensure if its fine to exclude the other certificates in hierarchy while PFX file generation

Please note i have given the certificates in hierarchy as i see when i see it in the certificate the lowest in hierarchy first and highest in hierarchy last

""-in C:\Users\YSW\SCI\prp\pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt
-in C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt 
-in C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt 
-in C:\Users\YSW\PCI\prp\AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt""

I would like to know what will happen if I continue with the PFX which is exported from the main certificate Or let me know how to overcome the issue of No certificate matches the Private Key error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [openssl pkcs12 command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs12.html) only allows 1 argument for the "-in" parameter.  So specifying it multiple times, it's only going to take the only the last parameter only which is why your getting the error message.

Normally if want to add only one intermediate certificate you can also specify the "-certfile" parameter to add one more certificate into the PFX file.  Since you want to add more than one extra certificate you best way to do this is to combine all your certifcates into one file.

All these files should be text files so I would combine all these files into one file and pass them all into as a one "-in" paramater.

e.g. (for windows)

```
copy pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt+TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt+USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt+AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt allcertificates.pem
```

(for linux)

```
cat pk.preproduction-abc.com.txt TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > allcertificates.pem
```

Then convert allcertificates.pem to pfx:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in allcertificates.pem -out preproduction-abc.com.pfx
```